# Unable to update to latest OpenPyXL version 3.1 or later using Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, version-control, anaconda, openpyxl

I am trying to work with the 'openpyxl' library and pandas but receive the following error when I run my code.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 message_data = (pd.read_excel('message_types.xlsx',
      2                               sheet_name='messages')
      3                 .sort_values('id')
      4                 .drop('id', axis=1))

File c:\PATH.py:495, in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, date_format, thousands, decimal, comment, skipfooter, storage_options, dtype_backend, engine_kwargs)
    493 if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    494     should_close = True
--> 495     io = ExcelFile(
    496         io,
    497         storage_options=storage_options,
    498         engine=engine,
    499         engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs,
    500     )
    501 elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    502     raise ValueError(
    503         "Engine should not be specified when passing "
    504         "an ExcelFile - ExcelFile already has the engine set"
    505     )

File c:\PATH.py:1567, in ExcelFile.__init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options, engine_kwargs)
   1564 self.engine = engine
...
--> 164     raise ImportError(msg)
    165 else:
    166     return None

ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.1.0' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '3.0.10' currently installed).
```

I have attempted to update the version of 'openpyxl' and confirmed that 'openpyxl' is installed correctly but the Anaconda navigator lists the latest version available as version '3.0.10' while the 'openpyxl' documentation lists the latest version as '3.1.2'.

Any tips on how to reconcile this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. I'll share both a minimal working installation of pandas that replicates your problem, and a solution.

#### example anaconda install using homebrew:

To illustrate: install miniconda from homebrew, use conda to install the anaconda stack into an environment called demo, then activate 'demo'

```
brew install miniconda
conda create -n demo python=3.11 anaconda
```

enter the env and check versions:

```
conda activate demo 
conda list pandas
```

yields:

```
# packages in environment at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/demo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    2.1.4           py311h7aedaa7_0
```

and

```
conda list openpyxl
```

yields:

```
# packages in environment at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/demo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
openpyxl                  3.0.10          py311h80987f9_0
```

now launch `ipython` and replicate the error (using a working `.xlsx` file that has loaded in the past with no errors).

```
ipython 
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_xlsx("demo.xlsx")
```

yields the same error you reported (assuming that you don't have the correct `openpyxl` somewhere else in your python path, in which case this error will be hard to replicate).

### solution:

The solution is to upgrade `openpyxl` manually using conda. To do this I needed to tell conda to looking the condaforge channel, and then upgrade (note that this is all within the demo env: `conda activate demo`):

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda install openpyxl=3.1.0
```

now you can confirm the version of `openpyxl` (`conda list openpyxl`) and confirm that `pd.read_excel()` works.

Two notes: first, if you don't change the channels you may get errors when you try to upgrade via the default channels, and second this seems related to an earlier [issue raised on the pandas GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41715).

This solution isn't perfect, as it would be ideal to only need to use `conda create -n demo python=3.11 anaconda` to get a working anaconda install.

Comment: This is a great solution, Arthur, thank you! I ended up realizing I could simply use my free Github Codespace access that I have through student email (I am in grad school). This has proved much easier for managing environment packages. I will likely need to revisit this solution when that student license expires. Hopefully the libraries are more compatible by that time.