ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.1.0' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '3.0.10' currently installed)
When using pandas.read_excel() I get the following error:

ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.1.0' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '3.0.10' currently installed).

My current versions:

pandas: 2.2.1
openpyxl: 3.0.10

I upgraded openpyxl as described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154244/unable-to-update-to-latest-openpyxl-version-3-1-or-later-using-anaconda-prompt, however it still have version 3.0.10 and get the same error message.
I also tried to uninstall pandas and openpyxl to afterwards reinstall them, however I get the following messages which load forever which makes it not possible to uninstall the packages:
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

defaults/win-64::anaconda-client==1.12.3=py39haa95532_0 defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py39_1 defaults/win-64::anaconda-navigator==2.5.2=py39haa95532_0 defaults/win-64::conda==23.9.0=py39haa95532_0 defaults/win-64::conda-build==3.27.0=py39haa95532_0 ....

What is the issue here? I never had this problem before.
Would appreciate any help.
UPDATE
I found out with the command conda env export -n <env-name> > environment.yml that I had installed pandas with pip and openpyxl with conda. Now I uninstalled pandas and I am trying to download it again with conda (conda install pandas). However, it does not work because I get the following error:
Downloading and Extracting Packages:
pandas-1.4.3         | 11.0 MB   | ###############################################################6                 |  8pandas-1.4.3         | 11.0 MB   | ################################################################################ | 10

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'tqdm' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.


How did you install the package? What command did you use?

Conda install ...

maybe you have two Pythons installed and you installed openpyxl in one Python but you run code with other Python - but Pythons don't share modules. Run print( sys.executable ) to get /full/path/to/python and use it to install modules /full/path/to/python -m pip install ...

print(sys.executable) gives me: c:\Users\user\anaconda3\python.exe

I found I way to see which packages were downloaded with pip and which with conda. And I saw that pandas was installed with pip and openpyxl with conda. What is the best way to proceed now?

I was in the same problem.
What I did was install openpyxl in VS, then in ANACONDA environment install the openpyxl package again.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
